# Has anyone seen WCF report that it had timedout after waiting 15min but really had only been working for a few seconds

Tags: wcf

getting this error message in the wcf client log

> The HTTP request to
>   'http://blah.svc'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:15:00. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

followed by

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:14:59.9979998. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
>   Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.

However the service call had been made less than a minute before this. Any ideas as to what could cause this misreported timeout?

It happens for more than one machine so I don't think it is http://www.andyfrench.info/2010/11/wcf-service-throwing-immediate-timeout.html

Setting the following timeouts

OpenTimeout, CloseTimeout = 30 seconds

ReceiveTimeout, SendTimeout = 15 minutes

Our server log shows the request as being successful. Before and after this there have been fully successful service calls. Its not a single particular method on the service either.

Comment: There are 6 types of http timeout, and by default in Windows they are all 1 minute. In Wcf client, you may have the config to have timeout more than 1 minute, say 2 minutes. However, if the server insists on 1 minutes, the change at the client side won't be useful. Somewhere in your client config you have 15 minutes defined? Can you post the service config and the client config? surely you need to blur out some credential info.

Comment: On the server we have a custom ServiceHostFactory that sets the endpoint binding to a custom basicHttpBinding. The client uses the same custom basicHttpBinding when creating channels. So they do stay in sync. Interestingly I changed the timeout down to 5 minutes, it still timed out within seconds but reported that it had waited just under 5 minutes.

Comment: Presumably you host the service in IIS, have you checked the timeout config of IIS at enterprise and machine level?

Comment: Yes IIS, will be able to check in a bit if those configs have been customized. Still curious as to what would cause the error message to say we had been waiting for 15 minutes

Comment: no mention of timeouts in either config

Comment: iis logs show sc-win32-status code 1236( connection aborted) followed by 64(ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED)

Comment: It might be time to call in system admin, or post your question to ServerFault.com

Comment: An old post but we are seeing this as well, any updates/findings?  We set the timeout on our server to 5 seconds which causes the timeout immediately but we are seeing the false "00:29:59.9863658" time in the error message. Our client timeout is 30 seconds.